# VR 3D Drawing Game From Scratch

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently doing a personal project to make a VR drawing game in which you can draw a 3D image in your surrounding. I have very little experience with visual studio and unity which i am using currently. Does anyone have suggestions on what i can do to get going in the right direction?

I've currently been looking online for tutorials and making a 'Frankenstein' code using what i have found. I can only do 2D drawing currently and have yet to implement VR. I can send out my current code if it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There was an easy to start demo in the internet like 1 or 2 years ago, but I can't find it right now. But I'd suggest you look out for it. Perhaps it even was the official unity demo. That demo already had the motion input covered and some basic functions. Good Luck on your project.

You find a good tutorial here:
https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/xr/getting-started-vr-development

And some resources here:
https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/resources-getting-started-vr

Comment: would a demo from a few years ago not be outdated? I'll take a look through those tutorials thank you for sharing them.

Comment: I think they should have a current demo, since unity usually is up date with it's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That is maybe a pretty complicated project to start with. But I think you should be able to draw lines in 3D with generating meshes at runtime, that are rotated to the viewer, or the hand. So you generate or spawn some Sprites at your controller/digital-hand position, rotate them so they face to the viewer and scale them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you i'll look into that and see how it goes